# ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python

Такая вот проблема:
Обученная модель принимает данные в виде:

```
a=([(1,2.33443,2,1)])
```

входе дает False\True

Но когда пытаюсь передать ее через input, чтоб дать возможность осуществлять ввод с клавиатуры - начинаются проблеммы

```
  ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-3ab1dd53c0bc> in <module>()
----> 1 tree.predict (a)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in predict(self, X, 
check_input)
410         """
411         check_is_fitted(self, 'tree_')
--> 412         X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
413         proba = self.tree_.predict(X)
414         n_samples = X.shape[0]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in 
_validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
371         """Validate X whenever one tries to predict, apply, predict_proba"""
372         if check_input:
--> 373             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")
374             if issparse(X) and (X.indices.dtype != np.intc or
375                                 X.indptr.dtype != np.intc):

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
431                                       force_all_finite)
432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
434 
435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[(1,2.22,1,1)]'
```

Comment: Проблемы начинаются наверняка не том коде, который в вопросе. В какой строчке проблемы?

Comment: Как выглядит `input()` (что именно вводится с клавиатуры?) и какие аргументы принимает и возвращает `tree.predict()`?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй применить `.strip()`, и конвертировать строку в float, пример: `float(my_string.strip())`

Comment: Такие ответы лучше давать в комментариях. Это не ответ